# How to get previous element with Iterator java

Tags: java, list, iterator, predicate

i have the following problem. I've been doing a task where the iterator is given and Predicate class have to check, if the String exists in the iterator. I overrode `hasNext()` and `next()` methods from Iterator. Hier is the PredicateIteratorTest. I get the message `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<Java [and UML]> but was:<Java [11]> at PredicateIteratorTest.providesValuesBeginningWithJava(PredicateIteratorTest.java:37)`

It should return the previous element.

```
public class PredicateIteratorTest {
    private final List<String> values = List.of(//
            "Java and UML", "UML and Java", "Java 11", "UML 2.0", "Effective Java");
    private Iterator<String> valuesEndingWithJava;
    private Iterator<String> valuesBeginningWithJava;
    private Iterator<String> noValues;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        valuesEndingWithJava = new PredicateIterator<>(values.iterator(), new EndsWith("Java"));
        valuesBeginningWithJava = new PredicateIterator<>(values.iterator(), new StartsWith("Java"));
        noValues = new PredicateIterator<>(values.iterator(), new StartsWith("Doesn't match"));
    }

    @Test
    public void providesValuesEndingWithJava() {
        assertTrue(valuesEndingWithJava.hasNext());
        assertEquals("UML and Java", valuesEndingWithJava.next());
        assertTrue(valuesEndingWithJava.hasNext());
        assertEquals("Effective Java", valuesEndingWithJava.next());
    }
}
```

Here's the PredicateIterator class. After `if(predicate.test(iterator.next())){` i want to do something simmilar to method `iterator.previous()` from ListIterator, but without using ListIterator, because tests use only Iterator. How can i make it ?

```
public class PredicateIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{

    private  Iterator<T> iterator;
    private  Predicate<T> predicate;

    public PredicateIterator(Iterator<T> iter, Predicate<T> predicate){
        this.iterator = iter;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            if(predicate.test(iterator.next())){
                return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public T next(){
        T elem;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            elem = iterator.next();
            if(predicate.test(elem)){
                return elem;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

}
```

I've changed PredicateIterator by adding ListIterator and then iterator.previous(). But now i have test error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:73) at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr.previous(ImmutableCollections.java:260) at PredicateIterator.hasNext(PredicateIterator.java:20) at PredicateIteratorTest.providesValuesBeginningWithJava(PredicateIteratorTest.java:36)`

```
private ListIterator<T> iterator;
    private  Predicate<T> predicate;

    public PredicateIterator(Iterator<T> iter, Predicate<T> predicate){
        this.iterator = (ListIterator<T>) iter;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            if(predicate.test(iterator.next())){
                iterator.previous();
                return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the structures presented only implement Iterator<> and not ListIterator<>?  What's preventing you from implementing both Iterator and ListIterator.  Then you would have the method you need.

Comment: You're implementation does not make sense to me.  Why are you passing an interator to the class.  Can you state the problem **exactly** as it has been given to you including any examples that were provided, etc.  It seems to me that `hasNext()` should just call `iterator.hasNext()` and `next()` should call `iterator.next()`  And you exception was that you tried to  remove or add an entry in an immutable collection.

Comment: A PredicateIterator<T> iterates over the elements of an arbitrary iterable data structure and provides only those elements which satisfy a certain predicate, while skipping all of the other elements. The constructor of PredicateIterator<T> expects the following arguments:

iter, a java.util.Iterator<T> for the actual data
predicate, a Predicate<T> object that encapsulates the logic to test the predicate

Comment: Otherwise, PredicateIterator<T> should conform to the specification documented in the Iterator<E> interface (however, you don’t need to implement remove() and forEachRemaining(…)).

The method test(T value) of the generic interface Predicate<T> checks whether the given argument satisfies the predicate. It returns true or false accordingly. A value of null never satisfies the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a boolean field and assign it to false but it in the the hasNext method after finding a value assign it to true and then check this field in next method, if it was false that's  mean you called the next method before the hasNext method, then you have to call hasNext method in the next method.

```
public class PredicateIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private Predicate predicate;

    private Iterator<T> iter;
    private T type;
    private boolean test = false;

    public PredicateIterator(Iterator<T> iter, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        if (iter == null || predicate == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.iter =  iter;


    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        if (iter == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            type = iter.next();

            if (predicate.test(type)) {
                test = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {

        if (!test) {

            if ( hasNext()) {
                T newTyp = type;
                type = null;
                test = false;
               return newTyp;
            }
        }

       else  if (type != null) {

            T newTyp = type;
            type = null;
            test = false;
            return newTyp;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.  I modified your `PredicateIterator<T>` class to save the value before doing the predicate testing.  It seems to work with the tests defined.

```
class PredicateIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    private Predicate<T> predicate;
    T value;
    public PredicateIterator(Iterator<T> iter,
            Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.iterator = iter;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            value = iterator.next();  //<-- save value before test
            if (predicate.test(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (value != null) {
            T retValue = value;
            value = null;
            return retValue;   // <-- return saved value.
        } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }   
}
```

One more observation.  If you need to alter any of the test list you won't be able to since `List.of()` returns an immutable list.  But you can pass that as a an argument to a mutable implementation.  E.g. `new ArrayList<>(List.of(...));`

Comment: Yeah, i've tried it but then, the tests show me error, because there was `value.iterator()` initialised, not listIterator.

Comment: I added ListIterator, but then i got error. Look upstairs.

Comment: It helped, but now different problem appeared.

Comment: Yeah.  It lets you return the save value.  Look at the change I made to `next()` and see if that helps.  `hasNext()` should still be okay.

Comment: `hasNext()` is okey, buy `next()` still returns an Exception.

Comment: If `hasNext()` returned false then it is correct for `next()` to throw an exception.  Other than that I don't what is going on.

Comment: `hasNext()` returned false, but there is one more item in the list and then `assertTrue` and `assertEqual` fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, i copied your `hasNext()` methode and changed `next()`, so it looks like this:

```
@Override
    public T next() {
        if(value!= null){
           if(predicate.test(value)) {
               return value;
           }
       }
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

First test `providesValuesEndingWithJava()` compiles now correctly, but now the other problem appeared. It throws an `NoSuchElementException`. Here's the test and the message i got. I tried to make with `while(value!=null)` or `while(iterator.hasNext())`, but then it compiles too long and crashes.

```
 @Test
    public void hasNextReturnsFalseAfterLastElement1() {
        valuesEndingWithJava.next();
        valuesEndingWithJava.next();
        assertFalse(valuesEndingWithJava.hasNext());
    }
```

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at PredicateIterator.next(PredicateIterator.java:34)
    at PredicateIteratorTest.hasNextReturnsFalseAfterLastElement1(PredicateIteratorTest.java:44)
```